# How do I stop the Microsoft Windows Search Procotol Host popup, to stop popping up?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

Often when I get into Outlook, I'll start getting these popup windows from the Microsoft Windows Search Protocol Host, asking me to sign into my Microsoft account.

[image]

There's always a checkbox to have it remember my credentials. I always check the box. It never remembers it, because it brings up that popup window again. Today it has become so bad that the instant I click the OK button, it immediately pops up again, demanding I respond to it. This has made using Outlook useless to me. If I get out of Outlook, the popups stop.

So, what's causing this problem and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

The Search Protocol Host might be prompting for credentials from older,
inactive mail accounts.

In Windows 10 the Search Protocol Host is now indexing data files from all
Outlook profiles, and that's why it’s asking for old usernames and passwords.

To stop this prompt, open
*Control Panel > Mail (Microsoft Outlook 2016) (32-bit)*,
select the older mail profile that matches the account listed in the
Search Protocol Host credential dialog window, and click Remove, then click OK.

Comment: There is only 1 profile in the Mail (Microsoft Outlook 2016) (36-bit) app, in the Control Panel. Do you recommend that I remove the only mail profile I have, then I guess reproduce it again?

Comment: I think you can create a new profile but do not delete the old one. Just create a new one to test the result.

Comment: Hi Perry, sorry for being so obtuse, but what do you mean by testing the result with a new profile? How do I test with a new profile?